# MVC how to reuse a view with parent class model

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, model-binding

Context: I need to reuse a razor partial view with 2 models like follows

```cs
public class Address
{
    public string CountryName { get; set; }
    public string CityName { get; set; }
    public string StreetName { get; set; }
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }
    public string StreetNumber { get; set; }
}

public class Customer
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public Address Address { get; set; }
}
```

The view should look like this: no **form** tag, no submit button, only the controls bound to the model

```cs
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.CountryName)
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CountryName)
```

The challenge is that the view should be inserted both as Address Edit Form and as part of any other form. The result is sent to different actions with different models. When it's just Address Edit form, there is no problem, the controls are bound to properties of the Address class and all works well.

The problem arises when I try to use it within another form, where Address is a property of a model and not model itself (Customer). I cannot just give the **Address** field as a model to this view, because the action awaits for the Customer.Address, but the controls are bound to properties without mention of Customer

Here is the difference in the HTML

```html
<!-- Edit Address -->
<label for="CountryName_input">Country</label>
<input id="CountryName_input" name="CountryName" type="text" value="">

<!-- Edit Customer -->
<label for="Address_CountryName_input">Country</label>
<input id="Address_CountryName_input" name="Address.CountryName" type="text" value="">
```

Is there a way to use this view in both cases? I started to investigate an HTML helper that would take

```cs
Expression<Func<TModel, string>> selector
```

but with no success until now.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Where are you calling the partial from and how are you rendering it? The whole point of a partial is that it can be called from anywhere. What you then do with the data is up to you. The partial itself holds the namespace of the model you're using.

Comment: The idea is to use Html helper in both scenarios like this: @Html.AddressEditForm(Model) in case of Address or @Html.AddressEditForm(Model.Address) in case of Customer. Or even @Html.AddressEditForm(m => Model) and @Html.AddressEditForm(m => Model.Address) But I will try to do it without helper, and see if namespace is kept

Comment: @melkisadek, Actually it doesn't work for me: I put @Html.Partial(viewname, Model.Address), and I have only CountryName in rendered HTML

Comment: You'll need to expand on how you're intending to use this. If you're trying to display an address for a particular (unknown) customer, then you'll need to call an Action in the controller with an Id parameter. If you're just displaying data from the model in the page then you should be able to access all the properties as normal.

Comment: @melkisadek, This is not a simple MVC scenario. I have 2 pages: one is the customer personal account page, where the form has it's own Address model; the other is a checkout page where form is much bigger with the Address section in it. The point is to reuse the same partial view that renders the same html, but sets the inputs id according to the nesting level of the Address object, either root (CountryName) or sub-property (Address.CountryName)

Comment: In that case you'd be better off using different ViewModels (DTOs) for the different pages, rather than accessing the models directly. It's good practice to have an individual ViewModel per View (or partial).